# Database check inside kernel

Tags: symfony4

first i wanna apologize for the unclear title but i couldn't think of a better way to put it to reflect the actual problem and if you can help me with a better one after you read the actual issue, i would apreciate it.

I have a project where my customers can request a demo of my application( think of it as SaaS) and so the script create a new instance of it and before the customer try the app and do whatever he wants, he has to do a short setup(set language,region,timezone,etc), afterwards the data is saved in database and he can do his thing.
But on a every access of the application , the script has to check whether this instance have the setup completed(in which case the customer is redirected to the homepage) or not(the customer is redirected to the setup).
And here is where the problem show up, i wanna do this check in just one place and take effect on every route the user may access, otherwise i will have to do it in symfony way and that mean autowire a custom service and use a method of this service on every controller i have which is time consuming...

I think the best place for this check is with the kernel class but i can't figure out how to use the EntityManager there so i can build a custom query...

Any ideas? Is there a better way to do this?(please let me know how and why) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is an event subscriber :). You're correct to think "I want to put this code in my kernel". Well, as the kernel processes the request, it dispatches "events" (i.e. hooks) that allow you to run code.

On your case, you should create an event subscriber on the kernel.request event. This event is dispatched on EVERY request, before the controller is executed. Here, you can do whatever logic you need. And, you can even redirect the user if you want. It would look like this:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $isSetup = false; // replace with your real logic

    if (!$isSetup) {
        // By setting the response, the controller will never be called
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse(
            // this assume you've injected the router
            // is redirects to some "finish_setup" route
            $this->router->generate('finish_setup');
        ));
    }
}
```

You can even bootstrap an event subscriber class in Symfony 4, if you have the MakerBundle installed, by running:

```
php bin/console make:subscriber
```

Cheers!

Comment: thank you,it was just what i needed. I may return if i get stuck upon something